# C# Outlook Addin w/ WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, outlook, outlook-addin

I have looked at several tutorials on writing general Outlook add-ins, and have gotten simple examples to work: items in menu, context menu, ribbons, etc.

Many of Microsoft's documentation has send me in circles, or is in VB, so I have run into some questions with what we are trying to accomplish.

1. Is there a way to add a custom control below the Subject line in a new email?  We need to supply a drop-down and add an additional header to emails sent for email tracking.  Right now the best I have gotten is adding a CommandBarButton in the "Add-ins" tab of the Ribbon, is there a better method?
2. Will we run into any issues installing for multiple versions of outlook?  (Will only 2007 and higher work?)
3. Can you host WPF controls directly in a Ribbon, etc.?  I know that WPF popup windows work just fine when shown from a CommandBarButton.
4. Are there some good links out there for what we're trying to do?

Comment: 1 - no, but you can replace the whole form (see Form Regions), 2 - i don't know, but I'd recommend to compile outlook-specific startup addon dll, 3 - no, Ribbon has only predefined set of controls you can use, 4 - I'm afraid only MSDN, also looks at the product called Addon Express, maybe you won't need to code much.

Comment: You should have put that in an answer, it was definitely better than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, not without implementing the entire message window.
2. We have to make 2 projects for 2007 and 2010, we are skipping 2003 and below b/c it is much more difficult and would be rarely used.
3. Can't host WPF in a Ribbon, we're going to display a WPF popup from a Ribbon button press.
4. Best thing I've found is to just follow the project template in Visual Studio and mess around.

Overall, our add-in is going to do the following:

- Make 2 projects for 2010 and 2007 that share a "Shared" assembly
- All reusable work is done in the shared assembly
- WPF is only displayed via popup windows (you can do a custom task pane, but it doesn't make sense for our add-in)

Answer (score 3):

2: Multi-version support is a PITA.  The hedge-your-bets approach is to develop on a PC running the version of Outlook you want to support; thus you may have multiple setup packages for each supported version.  Everybody tries to get around this though, but I've used this approach with success:

Version-Specific UI in Add-ins - Andrew Whitechapel - Site Home - MSDN Blogs: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/09/02/version-specific-ui-in-add-ins.aspx

4: Essential resources:

- Visual Studio Tools for Office For Office and Outlook for Developers Forums on MSDN
- OutlookCode.com

(FYI, I work for Add-in Express)

Comment: Funny, was just going to mention AiE, though every time I do I seem to get down-voted (maybe because people think I'm just being spammy?). Either way, AiE seems to be best route to go for multi-version support and allowing you to just concentrate on the code. But, as mentioned, it starts to stink when you don't have the extended functionality like `MailItem.HTMLBody` vs just `.Body`, controls, etc.

Comment: You can also use Redemption to access most of the newer Object Model stuff.  Luckily I haven't had to use late binding for any recent project I've done, and I've worked on dozens.

Comment: I also don't know why you're being voted down for mentioning ADX (funny you use "AiE", never seen that! I kind of like it), but I'm new here.  AFAIK, as long as you're up front about any "conflicts of interest" it should be acceptable to mention commercial products.  I recommend Redemption and ADX all the time in Microsoft forums, and they don't care.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I did not mark as answer since our questions were already answered without the use of AiE.  We are using Redemption b/c it is required to get around some Outlook security issues we're seeing.  Great links though.